# How to do Basic Authentication with an Axis2 ADB Client?

Tags: java, apache-axis

I'm trying to figure out how to do Basic Authentication with an ADB Axis2 version 1.5 Client.

I'm trying the following:

```
HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator basicAuth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
basicAuth.setUsername(username);
basicAuth.setPassword(password);
final Options clientOptions = serviceStub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
clientOptions.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, basicAuth);
```

However this does not work and the needed line in the message header is not being added.

Comment: Your code worked for me

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Got the answer from the following site:

http://www.inpc.de/blog/2007/05/axis2-12-basic-authentication.html

Apparently I was missing:

```
basicAuth.setPreemptiveAuthentication(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're close, your code looks really close to [this](http://wso2.org/library/161)?  The following is the difference:

```
clientOptions.setProperty(
   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.BASIC_AUTHENTICATION,
                basicAuth);
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is they removed that constant in Axis 1.4.x and higher.