# How to create a java client for consuming https://10.244.11.43:9443/services/BPELUploader?wsdl

Tags: wso2

I have one requirement to implement a java program for deploying BPEL on WSO2 BPS. In WSO2 BPS documentation I found `https://10.244.11.43:9443/services/BPELUploader?wsdl` i.e is we can call admin services with this link. But how can I build a java class Please WSO2 Team help me.

Comment: If you can get a WSDL definition from the web service you can use e.g. [Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) to generate a Java SOAP client from it.

Comment: WSO2 BPS not allowing to access without username and password.

Comment: If you mean HTTP authentication on the webservice then [you can do that with Axis2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528089/how-to-do-basic-authentication-with-an-axis2-adb-client) yes, but I don't know WSO2.

Comment: That does not work with WSO2

Comment: I'm surprised: if it's the same as, or similar to, [this BPELUploader.wsdl](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/branches/carbon/3.2.0/service-stubs/org.wso2.carbon.bpel.skeleton/3.2.1/src/main/resources/BPELUploader.wsdl) then it looks like it was generated by Axis2 - see the xmlns:ns1 definition. But fine, I'll leave this for WSO2 experts now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to download the web service? You can import the WSDL to Eclipse for Java EE Devs. and then right click / web-services / generate client. Once you got the client, you can write a java class to consume the web service.